# Can I add a column with a value calculated from joined table?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to populate a column on my transactions table using the difference between a timestamp in the transaction table and a timestamp in the user table. The idea is to normalize the dates to reflect at what point of a user experience the transactions happened (i.e. how many days after a user joined was the transaction processed), as such:

```
update transactions 
set days = ceil(extract(days from T.tdate - U.created_at)) +1
from transactions T join users U on T.user_id=U.id
```

For some reason, all the rows get the same number (262) in the "days" field after running the query.

Comment: You should add `where` clause to confine the rows you want to affect.

Comment: @ntalbs I tried that, but I want to affect all rows, using the same condition as the join condition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
update transactions
set days = ceil(extract(days from tdate - U.created_at)) +1
from users U
where user_id = U.id
```